# Reading an AS400 .MBR file to a flat file using Java

Tags: java, ibm-midrange

This is what I have been trying to achieve.

We are in process to let go a vendor tool called GO-Anywhere that reads data from an DB2 database after firing a select query creates a file writes data to it zips it and sftps it to a machine where our ETL tool can read it.

I have been able to achieve what GA does in almost the same time infact beating the above tools by 5 minutes on a 6.5GB file by using JSCH and jaring un-jaring on the fly. This brings down the time to read and write the file from earlier 32 minutes to now 27 minutes.

But to meet the new SLA requirements we need to further bring down the time to almost half of what I have that is something around 13 odd minutes

To achieve the above I have been able to read the .MBR file directly and push the same on to the Linux machine in 13 minutes or less but the format of this file is not clear text.
I would like to know how can one convert the .MBR file into plain text format using Java or using AS400 command without firing the SQL.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Well, we have no idea what an "MBR file" is or how it is formatted.  From a cursory Google search it appears .MBR (Physical File Member) is merely a container, so I doubt the .MBR designation says anything about how data is formatted.  You would need to find a technical description of the data format, and then navigate how that is stored in an .MBR.

Comment: A ".MBR file" isn't exactly a file; it's more like a partition of a DB2 file (or table). Without knowing the DB2 table definition, it's not possible to give a good answer, especially one that doesn't use SQL. An answer is technically possible, but it could take a good bit of programming perhaps with native API knowledge. And even with the DB2 table definition, it might not be particularly rational to do it without using SQL. "Clear text" is potentially the trickiest part.

Comment: In that case is there any other way of reading the file (not very time consuming) other than firing a basic SQL on DB2 ?

Comment: Rephrasing the question:  CPYTOSTMF+ FROMMBR('/QSYS.LIB/FLSSL.LIB/XYZ.FILE/XYZ.MBR') + TOSTMF('/OUTGOING/') +
CVTDTA(*AUTO) DBFCCSID(37)+
STMFCODPAG(850) +
ENDLINFMT(*LF)  Using the above comma the file can be streamed I found this here http://www.mcpressonline.com/operating-systems/ibm-i-os400-i5os/as400-integrated-file-system-solutions-part-3-moving-data-between-database-files-and-as400-ifs-s.html                        

Running this command from java using QShell one should be able to                           extract the file.

Comment: Doing a CPYTOSTMF first isn't going to be any faster than using SQL directly. It's going to be slower.  CPYTOSTMF isn't known for it's speed in the first place.  Second, you're going to be reading the data from disk, writing it back to the same set of disks then reading it again.

Comment: Do yourself a favour and forget the phrase 'AS/400'  If you search the web for AS/400 you will definitely get ancient results.  If you're lucky, you'll find some more modern stuff.  To guarantee recent results, search for 'IBM i'.

Answer (score 2):

You're under the mistaken impression that a "FILE" on the IBM i is like a file on Windows/Unix/Linux.

It's not.

Like every other object type in IBM i, it's an object with well defined interfaces.

In the particular case of a *FILE object, it's a database table.  DB2 for i isn't an add-on DBMS installed on top the OS; DB2 for i is simply the name they gave to the DBMS integrated into the OS.  A user program can't simply open storage space directly like you can do with files on Windows/Unix/Linux.  You have to go through the interfaces provided by the OS.

There are two interfaces available, *Record Level Access (RLA)* or *SQL*.  Both can be used from a Java application.  RLA is provided by the `com.ibm.as400.access.AS400File` class.  SQL access is provided by the JDBC classes.

SQL is likely to provide the best performance, since your dealing with a set of records instead of one at a time with RLA.

Take a look at the various performance related [JDBC properties](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/rzahh/jdbcproperties.htm) available..

From a performance standpoint, it's unlikely that your single process would fully utilize the system, ie. CPU usage won't be at 100% nor will disk activity be upwards of 60-80%.

That being the case, your best bet is to break the process into multiple ones.  You'll need some way to limit each process to a selected set of records.  Possibly segregation by primary key.  That will add some overhead unless the records are in primary key order.  If the table doesn't have deleted records, using RRN() to segregate by physical order may work.  But be warned, on older versions of the OS, the use of RRN() required a full table scan.

Answer (score 0):

Guessing at what is happening is that there are packed decimal fields in the source table which aren't getting unpacked by your home-grown method of reading the table.

There are several possibilities.

1. Have the IBM i team create a view over the source table which has all of the numeric columns zoned decimal.  Additionally, omit columns that the ETL doesn't need - it will reduce the I/O by not having to move those bytes around.  Perform the extract over that.  Note: there may be such a view already on the system.
2. Have the IBM i team build appropriate indexes.  Often, SQL bottlenecks can be alleviated with proper indexes.
3. Don't ZIP and UNZIP; send the raw file to the other system.  Even at 6GB, gigabit Ethernet can easily deal with that.
4. Load an ODBC driver on the ETL system and have it directly read the source table (or the appropriate view) rather than send a copy to the ETL system.
5. Where did the SLA time limit come from?  If the SLA said 'subsecond response time' what would you do?  At some point, the SLA needs to reflect some version of reality as defined by the laws of physics.  I'm not saying that you've reached that limit: I'm saying that you need to find the rationale for it.
6. Have the IBM i team make sure they are current on patches (PTFs).  IBM often address performance issues via PTF.
7. Have the IBM i team make sure that the subsystem where your jobs are running has enough memory.

Comment: If any of the answers solved your problem, please 'accept' it as the answer.  If not, consider editing the question to provide more detail so we can answer it.

Comment: Thanks for the above Buck Calabro and Charles. Both the answers helped ,  db2 export this I believe might be faster and would by pass java to retrieve data.Running below command always fails
db2 export to test.csv of del select * from SCHMEA.TABLE

 **** CLI ERROR *****                                                                    SQLSTATE: 42601                                                        NATIVE ERROR CODE: -104                                                         Token EXPORT was not valid. Valid tokens: ( CL END GET SET CALL DROP FREE HOL   D LOCK OPEN WITH ALTER.

Comment: Even this does not work

db2 -x -t "select * from SCHEMA.TABLE" result.txt

Comment: That's to be expected; neither of those is valid DB2 for i syntax.  There are three variants of DB2: DB2 for z (mainframe), DB2 LUW (Linux, Unix, Windows), and DB2 for i - that's the one you want.  http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i

Comment: Thanks Buck apologies for being dumb but is there an example that I can use to directly export a table from Db2 in CSV or fixedwidth format.

Comment: Does iSeries provide the data export/import functionality like Oracle export/import or Sybase BCP ?

Comment: DB2 for IBM i does not have a system-provided bulk export function.  I am a DB2 guy.  I'm not sure I'd call it a programming pattern, but when I need to provide data to someone on another system, I create a view or stored procedure and let them reach over to DB2 to get it.  If there's some reason that's not possible, and the sole way is to export from DB2 and import into ETL, I'd still create a view in the proper format, CPYF to a flat file and SFTP that to the ETL system.